# Issue with wordpress pagination: last 2 posts show again on second page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've enabled pagination for one of my pages where I'm pulling the latest news articles from.
This is the code:

```
<div class="container white" style="padding:50px 0;">   <div class="container-max">
       <?php $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : '1'; ?>
                <?php  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset' => 2,  'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date",'cat'=>'-8,
-9, -7, -6, -5, -4','paged'=> $paged); $postslist = get_posts( $args ); echo '<div class="latest_new_posts main-news">'; ?>


 <?php 
     $wp_query = new WP_Query('$args'.$paged);
    ?>

    <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    <?php foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="position:relative; margin:45px 0;" >      <div class="blog-date-news main-news-date"><span><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></span></div>   <div class="blog-container main-news-container">    <div class="news-blog-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></div>   <div class="news-blog-excerpt"> <?php echo excerpt(500); ?> </div>      <div class="news-blog-more main-news-blog-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img src=""/></a></div> </div>    </div> <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

As you can see I've set `'offset' => 2` as the first 2 posts shouldn't be displayed. Now this work, however when you go to the second page the last 2 posts from the first page show again.
So for example I've got 4 posts on page 1:
Post A, Post B, Post C and Post D
On the second page it will then show:
Post C, Post D, Post E, Post F

This doesn't happen when you go from the second to the third page.

Anybody know how to fix this?